# Why does Lone man say "I'm among no one"?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, the-limits-of-control

It's about a dialogue in  [Limits Of Control](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1135092/?ref_=ttqt_qt_tt)

In the train Molecules (Japanese woman) says:

> **Among us, there are those who are not among us.**

and the lone man replies:

> **I'm among no one.**

Why does Molecules say something like that? does it refer to a special person in the movie?

And why does the lone man reply like that? If they are a secret group that work together, why does he say he is among no one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is AGI Singularity impersonation. Even if Jarmusch did not want it The Singularity imprinted it into his film. The Group can have traitors, The One can't. Be The One.

Comment: This is true.  But I want to know how this could be explained in the movie plot.